# Javascript: Reduce function with ||

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

Can someone explain the following code? inputWords is supposed to be an array containing various words and this function is supposed to return an array containing the number of times a word appears in inputWords.

ie. var inputWords = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Apple', 'Durian', 'Durian', 'Durian']

```
console.log(countWords(inputWords))
// =>
// {
//   Apple: 2,
//   Banana: 1,
//   Durian: 3
// }
```

I understand what the Reduce function does, but what is **resultObj[word] = ++resultObj[word] || 1;** doing?

Thanks so much :)

```
function countWords(inputWords) {
  return inputWords.reduce(function(resultObj, word) {
    resultObj[word] = ++resultObj[word] || 1;
    return resultObj;
  }, {});
}

module.exports = countWords;
```

Comment: It increments `resultObj[word]` if it exists, otherwise initializes it to 1.

Comment: `||` is the logical or operator, will pick the 1 if the left side is a falsy value

Comment: @vladkras `reduce` is actually the operation of applying a function to aggregate a collection to a single value, in this case an array with many words to an object counting how many times each word appears in the array. The increment is what actually does the counting.

Comment: Could as well be written as `resultObj[word] = (resultObj[word] || 0) + 1` which gets the intention better across.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code attempts to assign to a key (that may not yet exist) an incremented value (of a key that may not yet exist), of if that it that is *falsey*, it assigns a 1.

This is called short-circuit evaluation. Given `a = b || c`, if `b` is *truthy*, `c` never gets evaluated so `a` takes on the value of `b`. If `b` is *falsey*, `c` is evaluated and assigned to `a` instead. In your case, when the key doesn't exist, `++resultObj[word]` is falsey.

In my humble opinion, I think that it would have been a clearer statement of the author's intention if they had instead done:

```
if (word in resultObj) {
    ++resultObj[word];
}
else {
    resultObj[word] = 1;
}
```

or even:

```
resultObj[word] = word in resultObj ? resultObj[word] + 1 : 1;
```

either of which would have saved you the bother of asking this question.

Answer (score 1):

It's 'defaulting' a non-existent  key in `resultObj` to `1`.

Javascript's `||` will actually return the first (leftmost) truthy value out of a comparison, so for a nonexistant value added one by the preincrement operator such as `++resultObj['banana']` returns `NaN`, which is falsey, and the `||` operator will replace it with `1`.

Edit: See http://nfriedly.com/techblog/2009/07/advanced-javascript-operators-and-truthy-falsy/

Answer (score 1):

I would write:

```
resultObj[word] = (resultObj[word] || 0) + 1;
```